# Нужно написать код, используя цикл while, который будет последовательно распечатывать в консоли номера билетов от 1 до 10 и от 15 до 25

Tags: java

Никак не получается вывести числа именно в этом диапозоне.
Выдаёт только от 1 до 10, либо все числа от 1 до 25.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int i = 1;
        int j = 0;

        while (i >= 1 && i <= 25) {
            if (i >= 1 && i <= 10) {
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
            }
            if (j >= 15 && j <= 25)
                System.out.println(j);
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так у вас проверка в цикле только `i`, а `15..25` вы выводите по условию для `j`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int i = 1;
    while (i <= 25) {
        if (i <= 10 || i >= 15) 
            System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: что-то туплю, а почему не `if (i <= 10 || i >= 15)`